# Clojure error - GC overhead limit exceeded

Tags: clojure, garbage-collection, large-files, fasta

I'm trying to randomly sample a large FASTQ file and write it to standard out. I keep getting 'GC overhead limit exceeded' errors and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I've tried increasing Xmx in leiningen but that didn't help. Here is my code:

```
(ns fastq-sample.core
  (:gen-class)
  (:use clojure.java.io))

(def n-read-pair-lines 8)

(defn sample? [sample-rate]
  (> sample-rate (rand)))

;
; Agent for writing the reads asynchronously
;

(def wtr (agent (writer *out*)))

(defn write-out [r]
  (letfn [(write [out msg] (.write out msg) out)]
    (send wtr write r)))

(defn write-close []
  (send wtr #(.close %))
  (await wtr))

;
; Main
;

(defn reads [file]
  (->>
    (input-stream file)
    (java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.)
    (reader)
    (line-seq)))

(defn -main [fastq-file sample-rate-str]
  (let [sample-rate (Float. sample-rate-str)
        in-reads    (partition n-read-pair-lines (reads fastq-file))]
    (doseq [x (filter (fn [_] (sample? sample-rate)) in-reads)]
      (write-out (clojure.string/join "\n" x)))
    (write-close)
    (shutdown-agents)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the same symptom I often get when I try to merge an infinite sequence into a simgle data structure like a map or vector. It very often means that memory was tight and the garbage collector could not keep up with demand for new objects. **Most likely the wtr agent is too large for memory**. Perhaps you may want to not store the printed results in the atom by changing

```
(write [out msg] (.write out msg) out)
```

to

```
(write [out msg] (.write out msg))
```

Comment: I think this will only work the first time the output is written as the state of the agent with change from the output to the result of the writing to *out* function. I wrote the code based on this - http://lethain.com/a-couple-of-clojure-agent-examples/